# Backbone.sync scope issues

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope

I'm currently using `backbone.sync` to send my collection to a PHP function, which stores my information in the database and returns some data based on his.

Everything works until the success function of my `.sync()`, as I lose scope of the model and collection so I can't update them, is there any way around this?

I've tried using two methods and neither seem to return anything, and I can't find any more information on the subject on here or Google. It's also in my preferences to avoid using a `model.save()`, as it's too many calls to the backend.

Method 1 ;

```
var that=this;
// some logic is done here
backbone.sync("update",this.collection,{
    success:function(data){
        // attempt to update this.collection here, but `that` is out of scope
        // and the scope of `this` is different 
    }
});
```

Method 2 :

```
var that=this;
var onDataHandler=function(data){
    // attempt to update this.collection here, but `that` is out of scope
    // and the scope of `this` is different 
};
// some logic is done here
backbone.sync("update",this.collection,{
    success:onDataHandler
});
```

Does anyone know a way around this problem? I checked the Backbone documentation and noticed that the `collection.fetch()` function delegates to `.sync()`, and yet the 2nd method is the one I use for my `.fetch()` and it works fine in keeping scope of `that`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var that=this;
var prebindHandler=function(data){
    // attempt to update this.collection here, but `that` is out of scope
    // and the scope of `this` is different 
};
successHandler = prebindHandler.bind(this);
// some logic is done here
backbone.sync("update",this.collection,{
    success:successHandler
});
```

[Further Reading on .bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you very much, haven't heard of the .bind() method before so I'll read up on that now. It won't let me accept your answer for a few minutes, but I'll do it when I can

Comment: Yeah, it's worth reading a little more about scoping in JavaScript too.